# How do I combine multiple and or conditions in octoberCMS query?

Tags: mysql, octobercms

I am customizing a pre built project based on octoberCMS (Based on laravel). Bellow is a existing query snippets and I want add some more 'AND' and 'OR' conditions in it.

> Comment out is what I needed to do In simple words or near to
> procedural style

```
$records  = DB::orderBy('id', 'desc');
$records  = $records->where(function($q){
                        $q->where(function($q){
                            //Get all employees
                            $q->where('assigned_id', Auth::getUser()->id);
                        });
//I need to add "OR (' "column_x" = "whatever" AND "column_y" = "whatever" ')"
                        $q->orWhere(function($q){
                            $q->whereHas('manifest', function($q){
                                $q->where(function($q) {
                                    $q->where('driver_id', Auth::getUser()->id);
                                });
                                $q->orWhere(function($q){
                                    $q->where('employee_id', Auth::getUser()->id);
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to make a request through the Model. Don't use Builder

```
  $iUserId =  Auth::getUser()->id;

$records  = MyModel::where('assigned_id', $iUserId)
    ->orWhere(function($q) use ($iUserId) {
        $q->whereHas('manifest', function($q) use ($iUserId){
            $q->where('driver_id', $iUserId);
            $q->orWhere('employee_id', $iUserId);
        });
    });

$records->orderByDesc('id')->get();
```